# How to properly use % or * (asterisk) symbols as a placeholder in makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a problem with creating "context-free/filename-agnostic" makefile to build C project without specifying explicit file names each time I add new ones. I have the following project structure:

```
include/ #dir to store all header files
    lib1.h
    lib2.h
    ...
src/ # dir of source code
    obj/ #temporary dir for storing all .o files
        lib1.o
        lib2.o
        ...
    lib1.c # start with #include "lib1.h"
    lib2.c # the same
    ...
    main.c
```

And the following makefile:

```
# dirs
IDIR=include
SDIR=src
ODIR=src/obj

_HEADS=*.h  #or maybe % percentage instead?
HEADS=$(patsubst %, $(IDIR)/%, $(_HEADS))
_OBJS=*.o
OBJS=$(patsubst %, $(ODIR)/%, $(_OBJS))
_CFILES=*.c
CFILES=$(patsubst %, $(SDIR)/%, $(_CFILES))

# compiler
GCC=gcc
CFLAGS=-I$(IDIR)

$(OBJS): $(CFILES) $(HEADS)
    $(GCC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

main: $(OBJS)
    $(GCC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to build executable if any changes are occurred in *.c or *.h files under `src/` and `include/` folders (not sure the changes might be under `src/obj`). So now the `make` do not compile because it thinks the object files are "up-to-date". So I probably do something wrong, since I need to check .c and .h files first.

Also I'm not sure (even after reading several tutorials) how to use % properly and what the difference between using % and * asterisk. For example, I saw something like these:

```
%.o: %.c %.h
    gcc -o foo %@ ...
```

How in the world the rule `%.o` is written as **rule name** (I suppose it's better if they are all plain names instead of some logical things)? Or it's make sense to do so **only** if you use placeholders like `%@` in the actual rule to avoid additional naming "overhead". Please, could anyone explain and help me to fix my makefile - I really messed up with these subtle things...

Comment: And how are the languges C and C++ relevant for this?

Comment: Because it's probably the common case of using such makefile in C/C++ projects.

Comment: It's just not c++. And c++ has many other build systems not only make. So this is just makefile - tag related

Comment: Have you tried printing the values of the variables like `HEADS` and `OBJS` and checked if they contain what you want?

Comment: "Because it's probably the common case of using such makefile" - Non sequitur. Sure, makefiles are used in C and C++ projects. But that is not a bijection, not even an injection actually. (Btw. I never saw the specification for that "C/C++" language, care to provide a link?)

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov I have asked you a question unrelated to the matter with the tags. This may gets you closer.

Comment: The output of `@echo $(HEADS), $(OBJS)` is `include/*.h, src/obj/*.o`

Comment: yeah you have no file called `*.h` so so it's considered up to date. I have given you some pointers where to go with this. If you are learning it is helpful to print the variables and check if they look what you want them to be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`*` is a wildcard which gets you a list and is "shell" related.

`%` is a makefile internal wildcard which will serve as a placeholder in a for-each manner (I will explain below).

While `*.c` gets you a list of all c files in one variable you can do more with `%`

```
%.o: %.c %.h
    gcc -o foo %@
```

This for example is called a [pattern-rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html#Pattern-Intro) and means for each `<placeholder>.c` and `<placeholder>.h` generate the target `<placeholder>.o` with the according recipe below it.

With the pattern rule make would generate something like this

```
a.o : a.c a.h
    ...
b.o : b.c b.h
    ...
c.o : c.c c.h
    ...
```

What you are currently trying to do would result in

```
a.o b.o c.o : a.c b.c c.c a.h b.h c.h 
    gcc ....
```

While this may be valid you have unnecessary dependencies. `a.o` does not need to depend on `b.c` e.g.

Also `_CFILES = *.c` will result in "*.c" being the string in the variable not the actual files. If you want to expand the actual filenames you should use the [wildcard](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html#Wildcards) function

```
_CFILES  := $(wildcard *.c)
```

now

```
CFILES=$(patsubst %, $(SDIR)/%, $(_CFILES))
```

also has this "for-each" like placeholer `%`

this means everytime there is `%` it will be replaced by `$(SDIR)/%`. Because you have no pattern for `%` to match though in the [patsubst](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html#Text-Functions) this will get strange. What do you want to achieve here? If you want to "cut of" `src` from the path it would be the other way round

```
CFILES=$(patsubst $(SRC)%, % , $(_CFILES))
```

But I doubt you want to do this. You should read a bit in the makefile documentation which is linked quite a few times here. I explains quite a lot.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Now % placeholder become much clear. However, I still straggling  how to make filename-agnostic building (according to the structure I provided in the post). May be it's not a "good" way of building, but I wonder - if it is possible (at all) to write makefile so that it will not fail each time I add new .c or .h files in appropriate folders?

Comment: The tools are there. To get all files with an extension you can use `wildcard` and to have a rule for those the `pattern-rules` can be used. Btw. can be that make already has predefined pattern rules for c/cpp files so you may not even need to declare them. The manual I linked for these parts also have examples where such things are done.